# UISearchbar custom

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uisearchbar

In my application I've added this searchbar:

[image: Image1]

I tried to customize the button and it works great, I'm using

```
searchbar.setImage(UIImage(named: "Filter_icon"), forSearchBarIcon: .Bookmark, state: .Normal)
```

and the button icon has changed correctly. Now I need to change the color of the icon? How can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your image rendering mode in your asset catalog.

iOS chooses the rendering mode depending of the context, an `UIImageView` image rendering mode will be set to original, when a `UIButton` image rendering mode will be set to template.

You can force its behavior in the attribute inspector.

First, select the image in your asset catalog. You'll see
 on the bottom of the inspector `Render as`.

`Template image` will override all colors to the tint of the view.
 Select `Original image` to keep the color of your image.
`Default` is the behavior I described above.

Of course your image should be orange *(like my tire is green)*.

[image]

Comment: It looks great, so if I select template I can override color of the icon if I understand. But, what method should I use?

Comment: It depends on the meaning of the color. If orange is the global tint of your app, or if it changes over time, template is a good solution because you can switch color by changing the `tint` property of the view / the window. Tint is inherited so child views will be the same tint as their parent when not override. Tint is an `UIView` property, not an image property.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is change your icon color and render as original color

```
 searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "Filter_icon")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal), forSearchBarIcon: .Bookmark, state: .Normal)
 searchBar.showsBookmarkButton = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem setting two different bookmark buttons. One blue and one gray like this:

```
searchbar.setImage(UIImage(named: "Filter_icon_blue"), forSearchBarIcon: .Bookmark, state: .Normal)
searchbar.setImage(UIImage(named: "Filter_icon_gray"), forSearchBarIcon: .Bookmark, state: .Normal)
```

I create two image_set in the assets.xcassets and I change this programmatically.